# ShareKit "SHK.h not found" downloaded from zip

Tags: ios, sharekit

"ShareKit "SHK.h not found" downloaded from zip!"

I've tried using git submodule commands but with no luck.
So I downloaded ShareKit 2.0 as a zip.

But the main problem is that "SHK.h is not found". I think it should be visible even if there are no submodules. I've tried adding Header search paths but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I integrated sharekit by following the instructions on the wiki and everything compiles but when i added `#import "SHK.h"` for part 5, xcode couldn't find it.

When you downloaded ShareKit you unzipped the project into some directory. In my case, I downloaded it to Documents. So, in my project folder the entire sharekit was under Documents.

In number 4 of step 2 on the [set up instructions](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) it says to change the user header search path to Submodules/. Since I had it in documents I had to change this to Documents/ . That solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I did exactly what you did and it worked. ShareKit is extracted in Documents, and userHeaderSearchPath is set to /Users/usrName/Documents/**